How can I get the client-secret of another client by REST API in keycloak 24
I am using keycloak 24/25.
I want to query the client-secret of an client by Rest-API. i.e. I use
https://<keycloak>/admin/realms/<realm>/clients/63e0cd9f-3993-4a2c-aa75-62f1f23eff40/client-secret

But I only get "***" as value.
I tried using an access token of the master Realm for the admin-cli client:
{
  "exp": 1720135430,
  "iat": 1720095830,
  "jti": "ce9eb60d-10b2-4110-957c-baeaf1d3e906",
  "iss": "https://.../realms/master",
  "sub": "0a4986a3-0074-42e1-b7e7-fdae1321a3af",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "admin-cli",
  "sid": "4f40f5eb-8c7a-4208-ad04-52cfd40b8340",
  "scope": "email profile",
  "email_verified": false,
  "name": "Admin Keycloak",
  "preferred_username": "keycloak-admin",
  "given_name": "Admin",
  "family_name": "Keycloak",
  "email": "keycloak-admin@..."
}

And a different client of the same realm with "all" access rights.
In older versions (16?) it was possible to obtain the secret.
Is there another way to achive this? Is it a bug in keycloak?
